# ASP.NET MVC - generating html for a View in a Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MySmartAnchor method that outputs a Html link.  Depending on an object that I pass to MySmartAnchor it will set specific css class and tooltip.

I feel like this is too much logic to put in a View. I don't want to add this method to HtmlHelper methods because it addresses a specific scenario. So I'm thinking of putting this logic inside of a controller and calling it from a View like so   *@Model.MySmartAnchor(someObject)*

Am I on the right track? Should this be done in a View, put inside of a helper method, or controller? I also thought about having a partial but it seems to me it is overkill for a link.

Comment: Maybe a solution would be to scope HTML helper methods. This way I can write a html helper method that is specific to this scenario and scope it to this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like good candidate for creating [razor helper](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/05/12/asp-net-mvc-3-and-the-helper-syntax-within-razor.aspx). If that's only single view specific helper, you should create that into same view that uses it. Else, create helper into `App_Code`, for using it across multiple views. Referenced article by ScottGu covers that as well.

Comment: I was about to suggest an HtmlHelper until I saw your answer.  Did not know that Razor helpers could be used at the app level.  Thanks!

Comment: Looks like scoped helper is the answer. I was confused because I thought if I create a helper method it will be available on every View.  I was able to put the helper methods in its own class and scope it in its own namespace that is specific to the View I'm working with.